# ERROR: Expression using IN has components that are of different data types

Tags: sas, teradata, proc-sql

I am using the below query in SAS Enterprise Guide to find the count for different offer_ids customers for different dates :

```
PROC SQL;               
CREATE TABLE test1 as
select offer_id,
       (Count(DISTINCT (case when date between '2016-11-13' and '2016-12-27' then customer_id else 0 end))) as CUSTID
from test
group by offer_id
;QUIT;
```

**ERROR: Expression using IN has components that are of different data types**
Note: Here, Offer_id is the character variable whereas Custome_id is an numeric variable.

Comment: There's no `IN` in you existing query. If this select is processed by Teradata `date` is a keyword, today.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely the error is caused by comparing the numeric variable `DATE` to the character strings `'2016-11-13'`.  If you want to specify a date literal in SAS you must specify the date in style that is recognized by the DATE informat and append the letter `D` after the close quote.

```
date BETWEEN '13NOV2016'd AND '27DEC2016'd
```

Note that there is no reference to any external database in the posted code. But even if your source table was `tdlib.tdtable` instead of `work.test` you still need to use SAS syntax when writing SAS code.  Let the Teradata engine figure out how to convert it for you.

Comment: Exactly right, and thank you for pointing out the correct format for date constants. A silly error on my part not to put that

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You don't make it clear whether this is being run on SAS or Teradata (via pass through).
I'm guessing SAS, in which case you are missing `d` after your dates (e.g. `'2016-11-13'd`).  Without this, the dates are being treated as text instead of formatted numbers.
The error statement is slightly misleading, as SAS is treating the `between` statement as an `in` statement.

Comment: OP's code is base SAS SQL, not Teradata, given there is no `connect to`.  But good point that OP could be misrepresenting...

Comment: Thanks for your answer!